# Summarizing row based data over 2 separate columns within the same table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've got the following table in Power BI:

```
    Date  | PersonID | Hours  | Age
------------------------------|------
02-jan-18 |    4     |   8    |  3
06-jan-18 |    4     |   6    |  3
01-feb-18 |    4     |   6    |  3
05-feb-18 |    4     |   4    |  4
01-jan-18 |    5     |   6    |  3
01-feb-18 |    5     |   6    |  3
```

I have rows of data up until a few years back for multiple PersonID's. Most people have multiple rows per month because the data is split out on separate days. For every date, I have that person's age at the time (in this case, PersonID "4" had a birthday between feb 1st and feb 5th).

What I want to do is calculate the amount of hours PER MONTH, PER AGE. My end result should look something like this (average hours per month shown per age):

```
    Age | Average hours per month
----------------------------------
     1  |   35
     2  |   31
     3  |   28
     4  |   28
```

I have no idea how to get started. How can I calculate a sum over 2 columns?

Comment: I don't see any `1` or `2` values in your top table. How do they get on the bottom table?

Comment: @AlexisOlson i am assuming the two tables weren't meant to correlate, or the top table is a truncated selection of his real table.

Comment: Sorry, yeah they weren't meant to correlate. It was just an example of the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a column on your table that will allow you to group by month:

```
MonthYear = EOMONTH(HoursAge[Date], 0)
```

Now you can write a measure that takes an average over a summarized table:

```
AvgHoursPerMonth = AVERAGEX(
                       SUMMARIZE(HoursAge,
                           HoursAge[MonthYear],
                           HoursAge[Age],
                           "MonthHours", SUM(HoursAge[Hours])),
                       [MonthHours])
```

Here's what the summarized table looks like for your given example:

[image: Summarized Table]

This would give the following result when you put the measure into a table with age on the rows:

```
Age | AvgHoursPerMonth
----|-----------------
3   | 16
4   | 4
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any particular reason you're using EOMONTH over MONTH?

Your formula didn't quite give me the right results (I think it ended up averaging over the different months rather than over the total number of children in that month), but it put me on the right path and my final solution looks very much like yours. I'd never used a calculated table before, so thank you for that! 

My final solution is the summarized table with a column for 1) distinct count of personid and 2) sum of hours. Finally I made a calculated column that divides hours/count of personid.

Comment: `EOMONTH` keeps the year whereas `MONTH` is just a number between `1` and `12`. E.g. if you want January 2017 to be grouped with January 2018, then use `MONTH`, if not, then use `EOMONTH`.